# increase and decrease number in loop with logical operators

Tags: javascript, loops, logical-operators

I was looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23568391/all-rgb-colors-combinations-in-javascript) and notice the way the loop

```
for( i=0; i < 1<<24; i++) {
   r = (i>>16) & 0xff;
   g = (i>>8) & 0xff;
   b = i & 0xff;
   colour = "rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+")";
}
```

increases the numbers and then "stuck" them to `0` with `& 0xFF`

So basically as I understood the value of, e.g, `b` will increase till it's `255` and then will result always `0`.

I was wondering if there is a similar way to let the value of a variable increase to `255` and then decrease gradually from `255` to `0`.

loop execution example of what I mean:

```
...
255, 254, 0
255, 255, 0
255, 254, 0
255, 253, 0
...
255, 2, 0
255, 1, 0
255, 0, 0
```

Comment: The number goes up because of the `i++` in the loop header. If you want it to go back down, start at 0xFFFFFF and decrement until `i` is zero. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Uhm maybe I'm asking the impossible but the goal would be to increment and decrement in the same loop

Comment: How about 255 - variable?